# Error on MSBuild.SonarQube.Runner.exe end command for Code Coverage Results

Tags: msbuild, sonarqube, sonarqube-msbuild-runner

I’m trying to run C# Code Coverage Results Import but get error on the last step.
I created .coveragexml file (named test.coveragexml) via visual studio (TEST -Analyze Code Coverage- All Tests), saved it in the project directory.
Run the following command at CMD:

1. C:\SonarQube\bin\MSBuild.SonarQube.Runner.exe begin /k:MyProject /n: MyProject /v:1.0 /d:sonar.cs.vscoveragexml.reportsPaths=D:\sTFS\24115\Sources\ MyProject \Source*.coveragexml /d:sonar.verbose=true
2. Build (via visual studio)
3. C:\SonarQube\bin\MSBuild.SonarQube.Runner.exe end

*For the last step, I’m getting this error:*

```
10:09:29 AM  ERROR: Error during Sonar runner execution
10:09:29 AM  ERROR: Unable to execute Sonar
10:09:29 AM  ERROR: Caused by: Error while parsing the XML file: D:\sTFS\24115\S
ources\SystemMapping\Source\test.coveragexml
10:09:29 AM  ERROR: Caused by: Unexpected character '?' (code 65533 / 0xfffd) in
 prolog; expected '<'
10:09:29 AM   at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [1,1]
10:09:29 AM  ERROR:
10:09:29 AM  ERROR: To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run SonarQube
Runner with the -e switch.
10:09:29 AM  ERROR: Re-run SonarQube Runner using the -X switch to enable full d
ebug logging.
10:09:29 AM  The sonar-runner did not complete successfully
Post-processing failed. Exit code: 1
```

Cannot find any character '?' at the file...
**From the log:**

```
M  10:09:29.021 INFO  - Sensor org.sonar.plugins.csharp.CSharpSensor@5945ac done: 12370 ms
10:09:29 AM  10:09:29.021 INFO  - Sensor org.sonar.plugins.csharp.CSharpCodeCoverageProvider$CSharpCoverageReportImportSensor@ed32df...
10:09:29 AM  10:09:29.104 INFO  - Parsing the Visual Studio coverage XML report D:\sTFS\24115\Sources\SystemMapping\Source\test.coveragexml
10:09:29 AM  10:09:29.110 DEBUG - Release semaphore on project : org.sonar.api.resources.Project@101ba81[id=37975,key=SystemMapping,qualifier=TRK], with key batch-SystemMapping
10:09:29 AM  INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
10:09:29 AM  INFO: EXECUTION FAILURE
10:09:29 AM  INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
10:09:29 AM  Total time: 21.544s
10:09:29 AM  Final Memory: 13M/121M
10:09:29 AM  INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
10:09:29 AM  Process returned exit code 1
10:09:29 AM  Creating a summary markdown file...
Process returned exit code 1
```

Comment: What is the encoding of your `test.coveragexml` file? Could you send the first few bytes (not characters) of it? The code coverage parser expects it to be in UTF-8, and the '?' character is likely to be part of the Byte Order Mark (BOM) sequence.

Comment: Also please mention how you generate this XML file, and also let us know if removing the BOM solves the issue.

Comment: Hi, you right, the file encoding was UCS-2, I convert it to UTF-8 without BOM and run all the command again. This time I got an error:
"Missing root element <results> in D:\sTFS\24115\Sources\SystemMapping\Source\build_VTFS-03-41-08 2015-12-23 18_20_49.coveragexml at line 1".
I generate the file manually from VS, as i wrote abow  (TEST -Analyze Code Coverage- All Tests, saved it in the project directory.)
I upload the file to here: [link] (http://www.filedropper.com/buildvtfs-03-41-082015-12-23182049_1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Finally I succeeded to create code coverage analysis!**

1. Moved the MSBuild.SonarQube.Runner to the same root directory as my project
2. Switched to OpenCover coverage xml and worked by the command specify here -
3. Ran the command from Visual Studio Command Prompt

*Here is the commands I execute (with 2 unit test dll’s):*
D:\SonarQube\bin\MSBuild.SonarQube.Runner.exe begin /k:MyProject /n: MyProject /v:1.0 /d:sonar.cs.opencover.reportsPaths="D:\SonarQube\6.5\NP\ MyProject \Source\opencover*.xml"  /d:sonar.verbose=true

Build MyProject

"C:\OpenCover\OpenCover.Console.exe" -output:"D:\SonarQube\6.5\NP\ MyProject \Source\opencover1.xml" -register:user -target:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TestWindow\vstest.console.exe" -targetargs:"D:\SonarQube\6.5\NP\ MyProject \Source\ MyProject.Test\bin\Debug\ MyProject.Test.dll"

"C:\OpenCover\OpenCover.Console.exe" -output:"D:\SonarQube\6.5\NP\ MyProject \Source\opencover2.xml" -register:user -target:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TestWindow\vstest.console.exe" -targetargs:"D:\SonarQube\6.5\NP\ MyProject \Source\ MyProject.test\bin\Debug\ MyProject.test.dll"

D:\SonarQube\bin\MSBuild.SonarQube.Runner.exe end > log.txt

Hope it will help others :)

Answer (score 0):

Your code coverage report format (starting with `<CoverageDSPriv>`) is not yet supported: https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONARNTEST-3

In the meantime, follow the instructions on this page to get Visual Studio code coverage imported in SonarQube: http://docs.sonarqube.org/x/CoBh

Comment: I tried the flow as described in : http://docs.sonarqube.org/x/CoBh,
strange, but the collect command ("%VSINSTALLDIR%\Team Tools\Dynamic Code Coverage Tools\CodeCoverage.exe" collect /output:"%CD%\VisualStudio.coverage") allways stuck. Ican see that it's creating a VisualStudio.coverage file that weighs 1kb. When "killing" the proccess and try to open the file, i get an error:

Exception was thrown: Code Coverage Analysis engine threw exception(s):
Coverage file "D:\sTFS\24115\Sources\SystemMapping\Source\VisualStudio.coverage" is invalid or corrupt.
How should I procceed?

Comment: Hi, I manage to get .coveragexml file as expected. The end command is finished successfully but no code coverage is shown on the dashboard.
From the log: ‘Code coverage will not be imported for the following file outside of SonarQube: D:\sTFS\24115\Sources\SystemMappingTestShani\Source\SystemMappingClient.Test\AspectTests.cs’

Comment: The coverage report generation and Sonar Analysis are running from the same directory:
reportsPaths=D:\sTFS\24115\Sources\SystemMappingTestShani\Source\VisualStudio.coveragexml
analyze /output:D:\sTFS\24115\Sources\SystemMappingTestShani\Source\VisualStudio.coveragexml D:\sTFS\24115\Sources\SystemMappingTestShani\Source\VisualStudio.coverage
link for the log file: [http://www.filedropper.com/log_1]